# Why is boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json's first parameter stream is not a const?

Tags: c++, boost, std

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/json_parser/read_json_idp909543808.html

```
template<typename Ptree> 
  void read_json(std::basic_istream< typename Ptree::key_type::value_type > & stream, 
                 Ptree & pt);
```

> Description
>
> Read JSON from a the given stream and translate it to a property tree.

I think stream  is supposed to be a const reference. Why is stream not a const reference? Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Most if not all stream operations are non-const, so a const stream would be nigh imossible to do anything with.

Comment: Streams are never taken by const reference.

Comment: @n.m. I see. stringstream represents istringstream and ostringstream. In this funtion we need istringstream part. and I think istringstream::operator>> would modify the pos indicator. So it can't be a const.